# object.updateWorldMatrix is not a function

Tags: three.js

As documentation of Three.js said, after changing the position of the camera, we must call the `updateProjectionMatrix()` method.
I'm doing the same. But it gives me an error like this:

```js
TypeError: object.updateWorldMatrix is not a function
    at Box3.expandByObject (three.module.js:6329)
    at Box3.setFromObject (three.module.js:6233)
    at index.js:66
    at GLTFLoader.js:147
    at GLTFLoader.js:1639
```

My goal is to put my loaded GLTF object, in the center of the screen.
And this is the code I'm using for it:

```js
this.gltfLoader.load("/corolla.gltf", (object) => {
            const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(object);
            const size = box.getSize(new THREE.Vector3()).length();
            const center = box.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());

            // reset OrbitControl
            this.controls.reset();

            object.position.x += (object.position.x - center.x);
            object.position.y += (object.position.y - center.y);
            object.position.z += (object.position.z - center.z);

            this.controls.maxDistance = size * 10;

            this.camera.near = size / 100;
            this.camera.far = size * 100;
            this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            this.camera.position.copy(center);
            this.camera.position.x += size / 2.0;
            this.camera.position.y += size / 5.0;
            this.camera.position.z += size / 2.0;
            this.camera.lookAt(center);

            this.gltf = object.scene;
            this.scene.add(this.gltf);
        },
            this.manageLoading,
            this.gltfLoadErr);
```

For the record, I'm using the last version of Three.js, it's `0.110.0`;

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like the errors is occurring here:

```js
const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(object);
```

Where `object` is the object coming back from the call to [`GLTFLoader.load`](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader.load).

According to the docs, `object` is not an `Object3D` (which is what [`Box3.setFromObject`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Box3.setFromObject) expects).

Instead, `object` is a JSON structure containing information about the GLTF data. The three.js example suggests `object.scene` would be a renderable entity (if it exists).

Take a look at the code for the `GLTFLoader` example, [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r110/examples/webgl_loader_gltf.html). Compare it against your implementation. You can also debug your code to see exactly what is `object` contains. Once you have a handle on that, if you're still having problems, come back and ask more questions!

Answer (score 0):

Short solution:

```js
var hollowCylinderGeom = new THREE.LatheBufferGeometry([
    new THREE.Vector2(1, 0),
    new THREE.Vector2(2, 0),
    new THREE.Vector2(2, 2),
    new THREE.Vector2(1, 2),
    new THREE.Vector2(1, 0)
], 90).toNonIndexed();

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(hollowCylinderGeom);
console.log(new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(mesh));
```